# VisualSVN Server working through IIS on 443

Tags: svn, iis, svn-server, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

### What I have:

Here is the context.
I have an Windows XP Pro machine where I have installed the VisualSVN Server (which is using Apache behind).

I configured VisualSVN Server to use the secured port **8443**.
(It doesn't really matter what port VisualSVN Server is using here.)
I can now access SVN by using this link:  **https://localhost:8443/svn/**

On IIS, I have some websites that I access using the port **443**.
I can access these websites using the **https** protocol like this: **https://localhost/**

---

### What I need:

I would like to access the SVN server without using the port, like this 
**https://localhost/svn/**
I think I need to redirect the traffic from the port 443 to the port 8443. ?!?

---

### What I've tried:

What I thought I needed was a redirect proxy, so I tried to use **SvnReverseProxy** that I found here: http://gstoolkit.codeplex.com/

I tried with VisualSVN Server working on 8080 and 8443. In both cases, same result.
The **SvnReverseProxy** service is running successfully, but is adding the below code to **httpd-custom.conf** (located on *C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\conf* )

```
<Location /svn/>
  SVNIndexXSLT "/svn/svnindex.xsl" 
</Location>
```

and then VisualSVN Server stops working, not being able to locate the svnindex.xsl file.

---

**So, is it possible to have VisualSVN Server working through IIS on 443?**

Comment: Can you use the apache behind VisualSVN and configure it to mod_rewrite the url?

Comment: is there any reason you can't use Apache only and switch Visual SVN to use the 443 port? That'd be much easier. Or bind Apache and IIS to two different IP addresses.

Comment: @jeff: I am trying to host on a single machine the VisualSVN Server and the IIS for any other ASP.NET stuff (and "Classic" ASP stuff that I'm still using) and access both servers securely. I tried setting two different IP addresses, but then I cannot set the router to redirect 443 traffic to two different IPs. From outside I want to be able to use let's say https://test.com/svn/ to access VisualSVN Server and https://test.com/aspstuff/ to access IIS.

Comment: @evnu: I didn't try mod_rewrite yet, but I will... I am not really an Apache-savvy. I tried the mod_proxy, but with this one I have some other issues related to the certificates. The error I get is not really helpful (The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.)

Comment: At this point, the [HttpPlatformHandler Module](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/) might be suitable for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for now the answer to 
***"Is it possible to have VisualSVN Server working through IIS on 443?"*** is ***"NO"***.

What I ended up with is having the VisualSVN Server working on port 443 and the IIS on port 8443.

On VisualSVN Server side I made these changes:

File: ***httpd.conf***

```
  ;>>> added:

    LoadModule proxy_module bin/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module bin/mod_proxy_http.so

  ;>>> on <IfModule ssl_module> I added:

    SSLProxyEngine On
```

File: ***httpd-custom.conf***

```
  ;>>> added:

    <Location /MyIISWebSite>
      ProxyPass https://my-domain.com:8443/MyIISWebSite
      ProxyPassReverse https://my-domain.com:8443/MyIISWebSite
    </Location>
```

So, now when I am browsing to

```
https://my-domain.com/MyIISWebSite/
```

my URL in the address bar remains unchanged and the content I get is the one from

```
https://my-domain.com:8443/MyIISWebSite/
```

It is not the perfect solution, but is the best I could come up with till now...